# Server Error in '/' Application. on Authenticate Directory services COMException (0x8007203a)

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

this is completely ODD to me. I can run this perfectly fine in local machine but when deploying it to server it fails...

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The server is not operational.

  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The server is not operational.


Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 

[COMException (0x8007203a): The server is not operational.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +627365
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeObject() +42
   ........ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +707
   ........Login.LoginUser_Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in c:\Users\.......\Login.aspx.cs:37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +160
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +93
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

Comment: This part is completely Odd. I think it comes with .pdb file Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in c:\Users\

Comment: looked at these, none worked, even the restart of server.

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with ASP Classic.

Comment: How about putting the code throwing exception in the post?